# Angular error TS2322:'Promise<Dish | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<Dish>'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I learn Angular 5 at Coursera and have problem with Promise theme. I just repeat a code of lector and have an error TS2322. Here is my service file.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Dish } from '../Shared/dish';
import { DISHES } from '../Shared/dishes';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { delay } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DishService {

  constructor() { }

  getDishes(): Promise<Dish[]> {
    return of(DISHES).pipe(delay(2000)).toPromise();
  }

  getDish(id: number): Promise<Dish> {
    return of(DISHES.filter((dish) => (dish.id === id))[0]).pipe(delay(2000)).toPromise();
  }

  getFeaturedDish(): Promise<Dish> {
    return of(DISHES.filter((dish) => dish.featured)[0]).pipe(delay(2000)).toPromise();
  }
}
```

And The Component Using The Service Is:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Dish } from '../Shared/dish';
import { DishService } from '../services/dish.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-menu',
  templateUrl: './menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./menu.component.scss']
})
export class MenuComponent implements OnInit {

  dishes!: Dish[];

  selectedDish!: Dish;


  constructor(private dishService: DishService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
 this.dishService.getDishes()
      .then(dishes => this.dishes = dishes);
  }
  onSelect(dish: Dish){
    this.selectedDish = dish;
  }
}
```

> Then I get error: Type 'Promise<Dish | undefined>' is not assignable
> to type 'Promise'. Type 'Dish | undefined' is not assignable to
> type 'Dish'. Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type
> 'Dish'.ts(2322)

I've think something is wrong with the service.ts file please explain to me.

Comment: Could u share a screenshot of the line of code which throws the error please

Comment: I can't add images yet, i'm new here

Comment: The issue here is probably the `tsconfig.json` file. You have `strict` or `strictNullChecks` set to `true` while this is `false` in the course you are following.

Comment: Just write it down as code then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getDish` and `getFeaturedDish` methods claim to be returning a `Promise<Dish>` but that isn't really a good assumption.  If you look at your implementation, you are filtering on the array of dishes, which could result in a dish that doesn't match your filter.  Thus, the return type of these methods should indeed be `Promise<Dish | undefined>` and not `Promise<Dish>`.  TypeScript doesn't know that your `DISHES` array will be guaranteed to include a dish that matches your filter logic.  I think the solution here is to change your method declarations to be be properly typed and handle potential `undefined` values.